# How can I apply a piece of R code to every column of my data frame

Tags: r, loops, filter, apply

I have to analyze EMG data, but I'm not very good in using R:
I have a data.frame with 9 columns: one column is specifying the time and the other 8 are specifying my channels.
I want to filter my emg data, but I am only able to do it per channel, but I want to do it for all channels of the dataframe at once, so I don't have to apply it to every single channel.

```
# This example computes the LE-envelope using the lowpass routine

# Coerce a data.frame into an 'emg' object
x <- as.emg(extensor_raw$channel1, samplingrate = 1000, units = "mV")  ##do this for every channel

# Compute the rectified signal
x_rect <- rectification(x)

# Filter the rectified signal
y <- lowpass(x_rect, cutoff = 100)

# change graphical parameters to show multiple plots
op <- par(mfrow = c(3, 1))

# plot the original channel, the filtered channel and the 
# LE-envelope
plot(x, channel = 1, main = "Original  channel")
plot(x_rect, main = "Rectified  channel")
plot(y, main = "LE-envelope")

# reset graphical parameters
par(op)
```

so instead of using extensor_raw$channel1 here can i put something in like extensor_raw$i and loop around it? Or is there any way to apply this bit of code to every channel (i.e. 8 column of the 9 column data frame excluding the first column which specified the time?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution. First of all, as there is no data with your question I used the 'EMG data for gestures Data Set' from UCI Machine Learning Repository.

Link https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/EMG+data+for+gestures

It is fairly similar dataset you been using, first variable is time and after that 8 variables are channels, the last one is class

[image]

To create a graph for every channel you can use FOR loop by using the column of your concern as your iterating operator. Middle code is same as yours, at last while plotting I did the change in plot title so it resembles with its respective column name.

```
library(biosignalEMG)

extensor_raw <- read.delim("01/1_raw_data_13-12_22.03.16.txt")
head(extensor_raw)

for(i in names(extensor_raw[2:9])){
  print(paste("Drawing for ", i))
  # Coerce a data.frame into an 'emg' object
  x <- as.emg(extensor_raw[i], samplingrate = 1000, units = "mV")  ##do this for every channel
  
  # Compute the rectified signal
  x_rect <- rectification(x)
  
  # Filter the rectified signal
  y <- lowpass(x_rect, cutoff = 100)
  
  # change graphical parameters to show multiple plots
  op <- par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
  
  # plot the original channel, the filtered channel and the 
  # LE-envelope
  plot(x, channel = 1, main = paste("Original ", i))
  plot(x_rect, main = paste("Rectified", i))
  plot(y, main = paste("LE-envelope", i))
  
}
```

At the end of this code you can see multiple pages created in graph section of rstudio, plotting each channel from 1 to 8 simultaneously

like for channel 5 and similarly for others. I hope this should help you to resolve your problem.

[image]

On the second part you have asked in comments : If you have the files separate let's keep it separate. will read it one by one and then plot it. To achieve this we will use nested FOR loop.
First set up your working directory, where you have all your gesture files. Like here in my case I have two files in my directory with same structure.

[image]

The changes in the code is as follows :

```
setwd('~/Downloads/EMG_data_for_gestures-master/01')
library(biosignalEMG)

for(j in list.files()){
  print(paste("reading file ",j))
  extensor_raw <- read.delim(j)
  head(extensor_raw)
  
  for(i in names(extensor_raw[2:9])){
    print(paste("Drawing for ", i))
    # Coerce a data.frame into an 'emg' object
    x <- as.emg(extensor_raw[i], samplingrate = 1000, units = "mV")  ##do this for every channel
    
    # Compute the rectified signal
    x_rect <- rectification(x)
    
    # Filter the rectified signal
    y <- lowpass(x_rect, cutoff = 100)
    
    # change graphical parameters to show multiple plots
    op <- par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
    
    # plot the original channel, the filtered channel and the LE-envelope
    
    plot(x, channel = 1, main = paste("Original ", i," from ", j))
    plot(x_rect, main = paste("Rectified", i," from ", j))
    plot(y, main = paste("LE-envelope", i," from ", j))
    
  }
}
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast answer! It worked and was so helpful to me! My dataframe actually did not include the 10th column "class" because we have recorded the gestures all in single csv. files. (so we have one file for extensor, flexor, fist, open-hand etc....) But I have a follow up question regarding this: If I bind my 8 gesture-files all together so that I get a similar dataframe as you used, that includes all 8 gestures: how would I do this plotting of every channel (as seen above) separated for every gesture? Best Greetings, Cel.

Comment: Hi Cel, I have added the answer to your question you asked in comments into my original answer above, by appending the new code into it. please check, I guess it will resolve you problem. If it works for you upvote so that it will benefit to others as well

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast response and your great explanation!! It has worked very well. I have wanted to upvote, but I am afraid, that since I am a newbie here I have not reached the reputation yet to do so. I get the message: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." But I hope I will reach the reputation soon to cast the upvote!! Best Greetings!

Comment: Thanks cel : )  !!

Comment: Hello Anup: I actually have a follow up question to my first one: is it possible to integrate all the plots that I got for the channels now into one plot, visibly separated by color?: I have also posted the the question in a separate post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848482/how-to-plot-plots-generated-in-for-loop-over-each-other  but since it is related to this, I thought I'd ask here again.

Comment: Hi Cel, I will check but I am not very good with graphics. Let me try. Meanwhile you can edit your question with data source information so that it reproducible. Use resources I have used. It will increase other people to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

If it is columnwise, use `lapply` and store as a `list` and assuming that all the columns needs to be changed.  (Note that this is not tested.  The `par` in `plot` may have to be changed)

```
lst1 <- lapply(extensor_raw, \(vec) {
      x <- as.emg(vec, samplingrate = 1000, units = "mV")  

      # Compute the rectified signal
       x_rect <- rectification(x)
     # Filter the rectified signal
     y <- lowpass(x_rect, cutoff = 100)

     # change graphical parameters to show multiple plots
     op <- par(mfrow = c(3, 1))

     # plot the original channel, the filtered channel and the 
    # LE-envelope
     plot(x, channel = 1, main = "Original  channel")
    plot(x_rect, main = "Rectified  channel")
     plot(y, main = "LE-envelope")


# reset graphical parameters
par(op)
})
```