# How can I extract processed emg values before apply a loop with biosognalemg package to a data frame?

Tags: r, loops, filter, apply

I am analyzing a data set with emg signal from 82 subjects, each column is a subject and rows are emg values, I followed the second answer solution from this other question: [How can I apply a piece of R code to every column of my data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67841029/how-can-i-apply-a-piece-of-r-code-to-every-column-of-my-data-frame/67842059#67842059) and it runs ok, here is an example:

```
library(biosignalEMG)
data(emg96627009)
colnames(emg96627009) <- c("subject1", "subject2", "subject3", "subject4")
for(i in names(emg96627009)){
    x <- as.emg(emg96627009[i], samplingrate = 1000, units = "mV")
    x <- rectification(x)
    x <- lowpass(x, cutoff = 200)
    x <- movingaverage(x, wsize = 100, units = "samples")
    plot(x)
}
```

I want to return a data frame with the processed emg signals from each subject similar to the structure of the original file (columns subjects and rows emg values) because I want to analyze them; how can I do it; I try to add to the loop

```
...
return(x)
}
```

or

```
...
return(x$values)
}
```

but they didn't work, only return x$values from subject1 from emg object

Other question, I have a list of data frames with data from multiple muscles with the above structure, how can I adapt this loop to work with a list of data frames?

Comment: Please share the structure of your data, using `dput()` and your desired output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: you can write a function, and apply this to each column of your data, and then combine the results into a single dataframe like so

```r
emg96627009_processed <- lapply(colnames(emg96627009), function(subject) {
  x <- as.emg(emg96627009[subject], samplingrate = 1000, units = "mV")
  x <- rectification(x)
  x <- lowpass(x, cutoff = 200)
  x <- movingaverage(x, wsize = 100, units = "samples")
  x$values
})

emg96627009_processed <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, emg96627009_processed))
colnames(emg96627009_processed) <- colnames(emg96627009)
```

If you have multiple dataframes, it is probably best to combine them beforehand and then repeat the procedure.

Comment: Hello Jonathan, I tried the code, but it doesnt work, return this warning - Error in `[.data.frame`(emg96627009, i) : object 'i' not found -  I dont know if I am doing and error, could you help me? many thanks in advanced

Comment: Sorry, in adition, I added x$values to my first script and then applied your code do.call(cbind, emg96627009_processed), but the result is a data frame with the 4 subjects with exactly same values; many thanks in advanced for your help

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, fixed it.